# Why is statsmodels throwing an IndedxError when I try to fit a linear mixed-effect model?

Tags: python, pandas, statsmodels

Given the code:

```
import statsmodels.api as sm
import statsmodels.formula.api as smf

df.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)
display(df.describe())
md = smf.mixedlm("c ~ iscorr", df, groups=df.subnum)
mdf = md.fit()
```

Where `df` is a `pandas.DataFrame`, I get the following error out of `smf.mixedlm`:

```
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-34-5373fe9b774a> in <module>()
      4 df.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)
      5 display(df.describe())
----> 6 md = smf.mixedlm("c ~ iscorr", df, groups=df.subnum)
      7 # mdf = md.fit()

/home/lthibault/.pyenv/versions/3.5.0/lib/python3.5/site-packages/statsmodels/regression/mixed_linear_model.py in from_formula(cls, formula, data, re_formula, subset, *args, **kwargs)
    651                                                subset=None,
    652                                                exog_re=exog_re,
--> 653                                                *args, **kwargs)
    654 
    655         # expand re names to account for pairs of RE

/home/lthibault/.pyenv/versions/3.5.0/lib/python3.5/site-packages/statsmodels/base/model.py in from_formula(cls, formula, data, subset, *args, **kwargs)
    148         kwargs.update({'missing_idx': missing_idx,
    149                        'missing': missing})
--> 150         mod = cls(endog, exog, *args, **kwargs)
    151         mod.formula = formula
    152 

/home/lthibault/.pyenv/versions/3.5.0/lib/python3.5/site-packages/statsmodels/regression/mixed_linear_model.py in __init__(self, endog, exog, groups, exog_re, use_sqrt, missing, **kwargs)
    537 
    538         # Split the data by groups
--> 539         self.endog_li = self.group_list(self.endog)
    540         self.exog_li = self.group_list(self.exog)
    541         self.exog_re_li = self.group_list(self.exog_re)

/home/lthibault/.pyenv/versions/3.5.0/lib/python3.5/site-packages/statsmodels/regression/mixed_linear_model.py in group_list(self, array)
    671         if array.ndim == 1:
    672             return [np.array(array[self.row_indices[k]])
--> 673                     for k in self.group_labels]
    674         else:
    675             return [np.array(array[self.row_indices[k], :])

/home/lthibault/.pyenv/versions/3.5.0/lib/python3.5/site-packages/statsmodels/regression/mixed_linear_model.py in <listcomp>(.0)
    671         if array.ndim == 1:
    672             return [np.array(array[self.row_indices[k]])
--> 673                     for k in self.group_labels]
    674         else:
    675             return [np.array(array[self.row_indices[k], :])

IndexError: index 7214 is out of bounds for axis 1 with size 7214
```

Why is this error occurring?  `len(df)` reports that there are 7296 rows, so there should be no issue indexing the 7214th, and the explicit re-indexing ensures that the indices span from zero to 7295.

You may download `df` [here](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/6160029/df.csv) to fiddle around with it if you'd like.

Comment: Thanks for providing the link to the data file.  Made it much easier to find the issue.

Comment: @Alexander No problem!  Thanks for finding the issue!  Made it much easier to get on with my day :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have 82 null values in `iscorr`:

```
>>> df.iscorr.isnull().sum()
82
```

Drop them and you will be fine:

```
df = df[df.iscorr.notnull()]
```

Per the function's docstring:

```
    Notes
    ------
    `data` must define __getitem__ with the keys in the formula
    terms args and kwargs are passed on to the model
    instantiation. E.g., a numpy structured or rec array, a
    dictionary, or a pandas DataFrame.

    If `re_formula` is not provided, the default is a random
    intercept for each group.

    This method currently does not correctly handle missing
    values, so missing values should be explicitly dropped from
    the DataFrame before calling this method.
    """
```

Output:

```
>>> mdf.params
Intercept         0.032000
iscorr[T.True]    0.030670
Intercept RE     -0.057462
```

Comment: Thanks!  Christ, that's a really misleading error... :/

Comment: I don't think `iscorr` is a function anymore, so instead you can check for columns with missing values by doing `df.isnull().any()`